# Using R how to plot and color with multiple facet

Tags: r, ggplot2

My `R` dataset (`migration`) looks like this:

```
date    gender  UK      USA      Canada      Mexico
1990    M       4.2     6.3      4.0         5.1
1990    F       5.2     4.3      6.0         4.1
1991    M       3.2     5.3      5.0         7.1
1991    F       4.2     5.3      4.0         4.1
1992    M       3.2     3.3      2.0         5.1
1992    F       6.2     6.3      4.0         3.1
```

What do I want to do?

- I want to create a plot showing the trend line by year of all `countries`.
- I want to `color` by `gender`
- Facet by `countries`

**What did I do?**

- I produced the following code

```
    ggplot(migration,
       aes(date,gender, color=gender)) +
    geom_point() + 
    facet_wrap(UK~USA~Canada~Mexico)
```

However, it does not work. Please kindly help me solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)

migl <- gather(data = migration, country, value, -c(date, gender))

ggplot(data = migl,
       aes(x = date, y = value, color = gender)) +
  geom_point(size=2) + 
  geom_smooth()+
  facet_wrap(~country)
```

[image]

***Data:***

```r
migration <- read.table(text="date    gender  UK      USA      Canada      Mexico
                              1990    M       4.2     6.3      4.0         5.1
                              1990    F       5.2     4.3      6.0         4.1
                              1991    M       3.2     5.3      5.0         7.1
                              1991    F       4.2     5.3      4.0         4.1
                              1992    M       3.2     3.3      2.0         5.1
                              1992    F       6.2     6.3      4.0         3.1", header=T)
```

Comment: Thanks for composing the answer. How did it know the variables were country?

Comment: @floss I defined its name within `gather`. I could call it `key` or `variable`.